# How to handle (x,1) base case for is_power(x,y) function, where x != 1?

Tags: julia

Title says most of it. Here is [a related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738908/finding-out-whether-a-is-a-power-of-b), but I do not have enough reputation to comment.

Here is the prompt:

*A number, a, is a power of b if it is divisible by b and a/b is a power of b. Write a function called is_power that takes parameters a and b and returns True if a is a power of b.*

In the archived post, the most upvoted answer was to address the trivial base cases of `(x,x)` and `(1,x)`. Then, determine if `(a % b == 0)` and then recursively call to find `(a/b is a power of b)`.

Here is the code I've written in Julia:

```
function ispower(a,b)
    if a == 0 && b != 0
        return false
    elseif a == b 
        return true
    elseif a % b == 0 && ispower(a/b, b)
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to stack! You could maybe also add the link of the thread to your question, so that other people can see it as well. 
And by the way, I don't see any other solution than writing it out. Or is your question if any x should be considered a power of 1? In that sense, any power of 1 is 1, so `(x,1)` should return false except for `x==1`

Comment: Hey Oskar, thanks for the reply! Yes, that's what I was guessing - for the power of 1 situation. Sometimes these power problems have interesting mathematical solutions, and thought I'd pose the question. Link added to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment if you multiply 1 by 1 you can only get 1, so the only number that is a power of 1 is 1 and no other number. Therefore, your function should return false for an input `(x,1)`, whenever x is not 1.

Then you should also consider the case where `b==0`. Then the only number that is a power of `b` is `0`.

So, I would write you function like this:

```
function ispower(a::Integer,b::Integer)
    if (a==b)
        return true
    elseif (a==0 || b==0 || b==1)
        return false
    elseif (a % b) == 0
        return ispower(div(a,b), b)
    else 
        return false
    end
end
```